# Copy database from site to new template; phpmyadmin?

Tags: joomla, phpmyadmin

Good day

I require some help with this issue. I'm not sure if it's possible.

I purchased a new template for my site. This template has a "quick start" option where it unpacks the full template into your local joomla install for easy configuration of the articles, modules etc. Everything is already in place.

My site has been live almost a year now so there is quite a lot of things in the database etc. I downloaded the site from cPanel and installed locally using Akeeba Backup. Now, instead of installing the new template on my old site, isn't there a way I can copy all the tables in the DB from the old site into the new quick start template?

I've tried it in phpmyadmin but it says I can't import the table from the site into the new template since they have the same name.

I hope this made sense. Basically I want to export old site database using phpmyadmin, then import into the database of the new quickstart template. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SP Upgrade https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sp-upgrade/
for transfer your data into the new site with same version of joomla.

Comment: SP Upgrade will work fine if the current version of the website is an older version of Joomla such as Joomla 1.5 or 2.5 and the new version is Joomla 3.x. If both versions are Joomla 3.x then SP Transfer https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sp-transfer might be a better option.